# Check if value is null in_array? PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to do the `in_array` inside of an If else statement. Where it checks if the value exists in an array or not.

Here's how I get the array values from ajax to controller

`$data_days = $request->dataDays;`

Sample output: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

If the user didn't check `monday` and the rest of the days are checked it will return the array like this `2,3,4,5,6,7`

These numbers are the number of days

1 = Monday

2 = Tuesday and so on..

and it comes from multiple checkboxes.

Well it works fine when the value matches inside of an array. But when the value isn't exists inside of an array it returns an error which says 
*in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given* because the value that I'm matching with my array isn't exists or `null`

```
  if (in_array('1', $data_days, true)){
    $message = "exists";
   }
  else{
    $message = "doesn't exists!";
   }
```

If there's no `1` value inside of an array it should return the `doesn't exists!` where as of now it just give me an error like this

> in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Comment: If no check boxes selected then the form will not post it. `!empty()` & `in_array()` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Manual:-

[in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

***strict***

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array()
>   function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.

So it's try to check  string `'1'` type inside array, and since there is no value related to it, it gives you NULL error message

Also use `1` instead of `'1'`.

you have to check `!empty()`

```
if (!empty($data_days) && in_array(1, $data_days, true)){ // use numeric value 1, not string
```

Or use `count()` with `isset()`

```
if ( isset($data_days) && count($data_days) > 0 && in_array(1, $data_days, true)){
```

Or use `sizeof()` with `isset()`

```
if ( isset($data_days) && sizeof($data_days) > 0 && in_array(1, $data_days, true)){
```

References:-

[empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

[isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

[sizeof()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)

Comment: The first solution is enough. The others not needed. Also you should add the reason why it is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

That is not because of the lack of existence of value inside the array.

It seems your array is not creating in a proper way.

But if you are sure about your array which is absolutely correct, check whatever your variable is an array or not.

using `is_array()` function of PHP.

[PHP: is_array - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

see:

```php
 if (is_array($data_days) && in_array('1', $data_days, true)){
    $message = "exists";
   }
  else{
    $message = "doesn't exists!";
   }
```